# MySQL - Using ORDER BY equals very poor performance

Tags: mysql

Using a MariaDB database containing a table with 1.7M UK postcodes, I am trying to determine the nearest postcode to a given set of latitude and longitude as follows:

```
MariaDB [dev]> SELECT COUNT(*) as total, postcode, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians( 53.18526 ) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(-3.01984) ) + sin( radians(53.18526) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM uk_postcodes LIMIT 1;
+---------+----------+--------------------+
| total   | postcode | distance           |
+---------+----------+--------------------+
| 1751331 | AB10 1AA | 276.23821854757585 |
+---------+----------+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.35 sec)
```

For the purpose of this example, I included `COUNT(*)` to show how many records are in the table to start with. Discounting `COUNT(*)` results in the query executing in 0.01 seconds.

I need to get the nearest postcode, so I add the `ORDER BY` statement:

```
MariaDB [dev]> SELECT postcode, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians( 53.18526 ) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(-3.01984) ) + sin( radians(53.18526) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM uk_postcodes ORDER BY distance LIMIT 1;
+----------+---------------------+
| postcode | distance            |
+----------+---------------------+
| CH5 3PF  | 0.13513453795504218 |
+----------+---------------------+
1 row in set (2.33 sec)
```

The correct result is returned but it takes a very long time.

The Google Geocode API is able to return the nearest postcode in what seems like instantly: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=53.18526,-3.01984

What can I do to return a result from my database instantly?

Comment: The reason this happens is because the ORDER BY forces mysql to scan the whole table for the right record whereas the other query without the ORDER simply grabs the first record it sees.

Comment: @Jeff, is there no way around this then other than to not use `ORDER BY`?

Comment: Your best bet is to use indexing to only scan the records of interest... but if I understand what the intention of your query is, I suspect it HAS to scan the whole table... My understanding of your query: Find the nearest postal code to __________ .

Comment: @Jeff, yes that's right.

Comment: What's your representation of a postcode area? Rectangle or just a dot? Do you use geometry types to store the value(s)?

Comment: Maybe try using a group by with a min instead of order by limit 1. This way it still has to scan the whole table but it doesn't spend time ordering all the records only to return 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve the performance problem!

### TABLE STRUCTURE

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| postcode    | varchar(8)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| district    | varchar(4)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| postal_town | varchar(35)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| county      | varchar(37)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| country     | varchar(16)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| easting     | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| northing    | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| latitude    | decimal(7,5) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| longitude   | decimal(7,5) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| type        | varchar(14)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| id          | varchar(32)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| latlng      | geometry     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

---

### SPATIAL INDEX

The latlng field has the spatial index and has been populated as follows:

```
UPDATE uk_postcodes SET latlng = GeomFromText(CONCAT('POINT(',latitude,' ', longitude, ')'));
```

---

### SQL QUERY

```
SELECT postcode, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians( 53.18526 ) ) * cos( radians( X(latlng) ) ) * cos( radians( Y(latlng) ) - radians(-3.01984) ) + sin( radians(53.18526) ) * sin( radians( X(latlng) ) ) ) ) AS distance
FROM uk_postcodes
WHERE MBRContains
(LineString
  (
    Point (53.18526 + 10 / (111.1 / COS(RADIANS(53.18526))), -3.01984 + 10 / 111.1),
    Point (53.18526 - 10 / (111.1 / COS(RADIANS(53.18526))), -3.01984 - 10 / 111.1)
  ),
  latlng
)
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 1;
```

---

### RESULT

```
+----------+---------------------+
| postcode | distance            |
+----------+---------------------+
| CH5 3PF  | 0.13513453795504218 |
+----------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my suggestion above in the comments in a sql code, just in case it improves the performance a bit:

```
    SELECT postcode
, min(( 3959 * acos( cos( radians( 53.18526 ) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(-3.01984) ) + sin( radians(53.18526) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) )) AS distance
FROM uk_postcodes GROUP BY postcode;
```